# How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, double-quotes

I want to insert an if statement in a cell through vba which includes double quotes.

Here is my code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "=IF(Sheet1!B1=0,"",Sheet1!B1)"
```

Due to double quotes I am having issues with inserting the string. How do I handle double quotes?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but are you sure about that string? It's a circular reference and doesn't start with an equals sign.

Comment: @JimmyPena I think that's probably just example code. I'm submitting an edit, regardless

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I find the easiest way is to double up on the quotes to handle a quote.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "IF(Sheet1!A1=0,"""",Sheet1!A1)"
```

Some people like to use CHR(34)*:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "IF(Sheet1!A1=0," & CHR(34) & CHR(34) & ",Sheet1!A1)"
```

*Note: CHAR() is used as an Excel cell formula, e.g. writing "=CHAR(34)" in a cell, but for VBA code you use the CHR() function.

Comment: I prefer creating a global variable:
    Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """" 'represents 1 double quote (")
    Public Const vbSingleQuote As String = "'" 'represents 1 single quote (')

and using it like so:
    Shell "explorer.exe " & vbDoubleQuote & sPath & vbDoubleQuote, vbNormalFocus

Comment: @gicalle 's answer is really neat, it takes all the confusion of 'how many single and double quotes' out to one definition where it can be documented

Comment: I use lots of global defines in all my VBA projects (when I don't have a choice in using something other than VBA!!) that define all the common things like carriage return, double quotes etc.

Comment: NEVER use `chr(34)` for this: there's a company, based on ProgresDB, using this, and every time their customer uses a double quote somewhere in a table, their application can't run any query anymore :-)

Answer (score 18):

Another work-around is to construct a string with a temporary substitute character.  Then you can use REPLACE to change each temp character to the double quote.  I use tilde as the temporary substitute character.

Here is an example from a project I have been working on.  This is a little utility routine to repair a very complicated formula if/when the cell gets stepped on accidentally.  It is a difficult formula to enter into a cell, but this little utility fixes it instantly.

```
Sub RepairFormula()
Dim FormulaString As String

FormulaString = "=MID(CELL(~filename~,$A$1),FIND(~[~,CELL(~filename~,$A$1))+1,FIND(~]~, CELL(~filename~,$A$1))-FIND(~[~,CELL(~filename~,$A$1))-1)"
FormulaString = Replace(FormulaString, Chr(126), Chr(34)) 'this replaces every instance of the tilde with a double quote.
Range("WorkbookFileName").Formula = FormulaString
```

This is really just a simple programming trick, but it makes entering the formula in your VBA code pretty easy.

Answer (score 13):

All double quotes inside double quotes which suround the string must be changed doubled. As example I had one of json file strings : "delivery": "Standard", 
In Vba Editor I changed it into  """delivery"": ""Standard""," and everythig works correctly. If you have to insert a lot of similar strings, my proposal first, insert them all between "" , then with VBA editor replace " inside into "". If you will do mistake, VBA editor shows this line in red and you will correct this error.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a small routine which copies formula from a cell to clipboard which one can easily paste in Visual Basic Editor.

```
    Public Sub CopyExcelFormulaInVBAFormat()
        Dim strFormula As String
        Dim objDataObj As Object

        '\Check that single cell is selected!
       If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Select single cell only!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Check if we are not on a blank cell!
       If Len(ActiveCell.Formula) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Formula To Copy!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Add quotes as required in VBE
       strFormula = Chr(34) & Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34)

        'This is ClsID of MSFORMS Data Object
       Set objDataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        objDataObj.SetText strFormula, 1
        objDataObj.PutInClipboard
        MsgBox "VBA Format formula copied to Clipboard!", vbInformation

        Set objDataObj = Nothing

    End Sub
```

It is originally posted on Chandoo.org forums' [Vault](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/copy-formula-from-excel-to-clipboard-in-vba-compatible-format.35997/) Section.

Answer (score 4):

In case the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba#comment40325504_9024764) by [gicalle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2033088/gicalle) ever dies:

> I prefer creating a global variable:
>
> ```
> Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """" 'represents 1 double quote (")
> Public Const vbSingleQuote As String = "'" 'represents 1 single quote (')
> ```
>
> and using it like so:
>
> ```
> Shell "explorer.exe " & vbDoubleQuote & sPath & vbDoubleQuote, vbNormalFocus
> ```