# SUMIF equation in worksheet not working with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have lists of  $ sale amounts in one column and then another column near it that shows if it's a "YOR" for sales or "RE" for returns and I want to sum the dollar figures of the YORs.

I have an equation that I am trying to insert into a worksheet using a macro. When you run the macro there is a cell in H16 that should fill in with the resulting total sale number

There's a variable entitled CellNumber (Long) that holds the # of items in the list. 
VA05NDump is the name of the worksheet with the data.

```
Range("H16").FormulaR1C1 = "SUMIF((VA05NDump!R2C3:VA05NDump!R"&CellNumber&"C3),"YOR",R2C13:R"&CellNumber&"C13)
```

when I click out of the equation in VBA it says "compile error" expected: end of statement" and highlights what is inside this bracket: ["C3),"]

I've tried changing the "YOR" to ="YOR" and "=YOR" but that doesn't change anything.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("H16").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF((VA05NDump!R2C3:VA05NDump!R" & CellNumber & _
    "C3),""YOR"",R2C13:R" & CellNumber & "C13)"
```

**Revisions:**
1. Added `=` sign upfront.
2. Double quoted `YOR` in this part: `"C3),""YOR"",R2C13:R"`. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba) which discusses ways of putting double quotes which applies to all strings in `""` for worksheet formulas.
3. Added the missing `"` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked perfectly. I'm surprised I missed the first "=" but it was pretty late when I was working on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `"` at the end and probably a `=` at the beginning of your formula.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that I have previous entered a formula into a cell.
It is done by entering the formula as a string into the cell.

```
'Make Formula into a string
Dim Formula As String
Formula = "=SUMIF((VA05NDump!R2C3:VA05NDump!R" & CellNumber & _
           "C3)," & chr(34) & "YOR" & chr(34) & ",R2C13:R" & CellNumber & "C13)"

'Activate the desired range
Range("H16").Activate

'Enter formula string into active cell
ActiveCell = Formula
```

Also "Chr(34)" can be used as ". I find this help to create a string where
   chr(34) & "YOR" & chr(34) = ""YOR"" so when it is entered into the cell it becomes "YOR"

Comment: Thanks. that's useful. I'm going to rewrite some of it using this approach.