# Inserting a formula containing an ampersand into a cell

Tags: string, vba, excel, escaping

I'm trying to create a formula in the A1 cell which contains an ampersand character that looks something like this in Excel:

```
="Hello, "&A2
```

My VBA code is as follows:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=""Hello, "" & "&A2"
```

VBA is throwing errors, and I can't figure out why. I've tried using double ampersands, and double quotes in various places and can't get around this error.

Comment: It looks like that rather than the ampersand, you just have the extra double quote. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291221/inserting-a-formula-containing-an-ampersand-into-a-cell#comments-33291258) // See also: [excel - How do I put double quotes in a string in vba? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
   Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & "Hello" & Chr(34) & "& A2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this pithy line:

```
[a1] = "=""Hello, "" & A2"
```

...which will evaluate to, "Hello, Dave"

Comment: Say he was working in Sheet2 - using `[a1]` would refer to Sheet2's A1, correct? So to be sure, would `Sheets("Sheet1").[a1]` work? Or do the brackets not work that way?

Comment: If no sheet object is specified, then the result will be the active sheet. You can do what you wrote in your comment. And, you can also do: `[sheet1!a1]`

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra `"`:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=""Hello, "" & A2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&` character code of 38:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & "Hello, " & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & "A2"
```

Comment: Wouldn't this insert the formula, `=Hello, &A2`, without the quotes around the string?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well.

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""hello "" & A2"
```

Comment: I want the formula in cell A1 to be  `="Hello, "&A2 `. So if the value of A2 is "Dave", then the formula in cell A1 should evaluate to "Hello, Dave"

Comment: I think you were confusing everybody because of the "ampersand " in the  title, edited code

Comment: Thanks. That's why I provided the formula I'm attempting to insert.

Comment: When you have a working formula, record a macro, go into the formula bar and hit enter, then stop recording, go to the VBA editor to see what the formula looks like.