# Access OutPutTo to folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been struggling to output the PDF report to the relevant folder within the server. The error which is showing is

> RunTime error 3201, no record found.

Could you please help me to solve it?

```
Dim RFQNumber As String
Dim InNumber As String
Dim FullReportName As String
Dim path1 As String

RFQNumber = [Forms]![RFQ_Database]![RFQ_ExNumber]
InNumber = [Forms]![RFQ_Database]![RFQ_InNumber]
path1 = "\\AZBAK-FP02\Work\Old Server Data\V&C\" & RFQNumber & "\" & RFQNumber & " " & InNumber & ".pdf"

MsgBox (path1)

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "AOrderFCAVienna", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", path1, False
```

Comment: Have you step debugged? Are expected values retrieved from form? Which line throws error? I don't see anything wrong with OutputTo line although I prefer `acFormatPDF` for the OutputFormat parameter. Do you have permission to write to folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the ampersand in the directory path is causing the issue.

```
ath1 = "\\AZBAK-FP02\Work\Old Server Data\V&C\" & RFQNumber & "\" & RFQNumber & " " & InNumber & ".pdf"
                                          ^^^
```

you may need to add chr code

```
ath1 = "\\AZBAK-FP02\Work\Old Server Data\V" & Chr(38) & "C\" & RFQNumber & "\" & RFQNumber & " " & InNumber & ".pdf"
```

[Inserting a formula containing an ampersand into a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291221/inserting-a-formula-containing-an-ampersand-into-a-cell)