# r1c1 and excel formula yields error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have made this very simple loop to apply a formula to all cells in a range:

```
For Each cell In Range("G5:G500")
    cell.Offset(0, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4]>0),(RC[-2])/(RC[-4]),"")"
Next
```

It gives "application-defined or object-defined error" for the line

```
cell.Offset(0, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4]>0),(RC[-2])/(RC[-4]),"")"
```

I can't work out where i'm going wrong here. I've tried:

- Various different formats of R1C1 (e.g RC[1] or R[]C[1])
- using formula instead of R1C1 but then I can't refer to cells geometrically
- I'm pretty sure all my bracketing is correct

very baffled and would really appreciate a tip or hint on this!

Comment: I think the IF formula needs an ending paranthesis:`cell.Offset(0, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4]>0),(RC[-2])/(RC[-4]),"")"`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba. You have quotation marks in a string. So `.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4]>0),(RC[-2])/(RC[-4]),"""")"`will work.

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4])>0,RC[-2]/RC[-4],"""")"` will better suit what you probably want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this before! Change 0 to 0.001 or something small and wrap it in an IFERROR formula to stop errors that come from having vba do the formula! and that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the issue is, but when i change your code to

```
For Each cell In Range("G5:G500")
    cell.Offset(0, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4]>0),(RC[-2])/(RC[-4]),N/A)"
Next
```

it works fine. So probably issue in if statement with "" inserted in cell... (i will make a deeper look)

edit:
yes, issue with was bracket as someone mentioned in comment

```
For Each cell In Range("G5:G500")
    cell.Offset(0, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Len(RC[-4]>0),(RC[-2])/(RC[-4]),)"
Next
```