# Assigning a string to a variable in Access VBA that contains double quotations

Tags: variables, ms-access, vba

Consider this simple coding in Access VBA:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM 1 where [1.how] ="good""
```

Because of the double quote surrounding the word "good", I am getting this compile error:

> "expected end of statement"

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: double every double quotes inside the string: `sql = "SELECT * FROM 1 where [1.how] =""good"""`

Comment: thank you it worked,can you rewrite it in a separate answer so i can choose it as the right answer

Comment: Or you could upvote this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024764/6216216 (which this question is a duplicate of) -- after all you should have found this all by yourself by searching stackoverflow for `vba double quotes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double every double quotes inside the string:

`sql = "SELECT * FROM 1 where [1.how] =""good"""`