# VBA Dragging formula until the last row

Tags: vba, excel

Please when i run this code it works liek charm

```
Sub drag()
'
' drag Macro
'

'
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("WIP")

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("WIP").Select
    Range("N2:N" & lastRow).Formula = "=G3&"",""&L3"

End Sub
```

The problem is that when i want to replace the formula by this one :

```
=IF(RIGHT(F2;1)="k";"kit";IF(H2="LIM-mètre linéaire";"tissu";"composant"))
```

i can't run the code please any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9024724/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIRST try changing your semicolons to commas, then if that doesnt work

try

```
=IF(RIGHT(F2;1)="""k""","""kit""",IF(H2="""LIM-mètre linéaire""","""tissu""","""composant"""))
```