# Quotation marks in Word macros

Tags: vba, ms-word, double-quotes

I am trying to use a Word macro to find and replace some text. Part of my original text is in italics (Our Notebook), and I want the replacement text to instead enclose those italicized words in quotation marks ("Our Notebook") and remove the italics. My 'bad' code is show below. Is there a simple fix for this?

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "From Our Notebook"
    .Replacement.Text = "From "Our NoteBook""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks, Orphid. I looked that other post up, but either I didn't understand their recommended solution, or it didn't work for my case.

Comment: The usage of `Chr(34)` would look like this: `.Replacement.Text = "From " & Chr(34) & "Out NoteBook" & Chr(34)`.

Comment: @Orphid VTC as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured this out. The solution is to use two double quotation marks to indicate an output of single double quotation mark. Since these have to go inside a set of double quotation marks (e.g., .Replacement.Text = "From ""Our NoteBook"""), you end up with a lot of quotation marks!