# VBA Setting Formula in Range - Problems

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem. I want to fill in the formula (`=""`) in different cells, it is necessary to fill in this kind of formula instead of leaving the cells empty due to processing by another file. However, if I loop over the different cells, in the following way:

```
For Col = 10 To 99
    For Row = 10 To 11
        If Col Mod 3 <> 0 Then
           Worksheets(name_sheet).Range("A1").Offset(Row - 1, Col - 1).Formula = "="""
           Worksheets(name_sheet).Range("A1").Offset(Row - 1, Col - 1).Locked = True
           Worksheets(name_sheet).Range("A1").Offset(Row - 1, Col - 1).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
           Worksheets(name_sheet).Range("A1").Offset(Row - 1, Col - 1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
       End If
    Next Row
Next Col
```

Then I receive an error that the formula can not be assigned. Nevertheless I do not see what does the error produces.

Thanks a lot for your help

Kind Regards
Claude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing Double Quotes Within a String in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960548/placing-double-quotes-within-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda confusing when you try to put `"` in cell via VBA. You need to escape it with `"`...

Try this:

```
"="""""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really, only that little mistake of not having enough " in the formula. I wanted to write the formula ="" and in transforming it into the code I missed some "" . Thanks a lot

Comment: @ClaudeG Remember that you can always record a macro of putting such a formula in a cell and check auto-generated code.

Answer (score 2):

I like using the `Chr(34)` to get the double `"` symbol:

```
Worksheets(name_sheet).Range("A1").Offset(Row - 1, Col - 1).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to escape quotes, so they are not interpreted as quotes delimiting your string.

For instance, use

```
Worksheets(name_sheet).Range("A1").Offset(Row - 1, Col - 1).Formula = "="""""
```