# VBA : Sumif function not working

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am writing a code for sum the data based on criteria. The below code working perfectly but it not return value. The code works on the excel like this `(= SUMIF($B$1:$DC$1,p,B2:DD2)`. The reason is Criteria `P` Need double quotation.how to add the double quotation to `P` and any suggestion would be appreciated

```
Sub ashok()
 Dim LR As Long
 Dim Rg, Rg1 As Range

                ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
                LR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
                Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
                ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
                Set Rg = Range("b1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
                Set Rg1 = Range("b2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlToRight))
                Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Select

                With ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Resize(LR)
                .Formula = "= SumIf(" & Rg.Address(True, True) & "," & "P" & "," & Rg1.Address(False, False) & ")"
                End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing Double Quotes Within a String in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960548/placing-double-quotes-within-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is use `Chr(34)`:

```
.Formula = "= SumIf(" & Rg.Address(True, True) & "," & Chr(34) & "P" & Chr(34) & "," & Rg1.Address(False, False) & ")"
```

**However**, you have way too much (unnecessary and should stay away from) use of `Select`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell` and `Selection`.

An example of how your code could look if you use fully qualified objects:

```
With Sheets("Sheet3") ' <-- replace with your sheet's name

    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0"

    Set Rg = .Range("B1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)) '<-- NOT SURE this make sense !
    Set Rg1 = .Range("B2", .Range("A2").End(xlToRight)) '<-- NOT SURE this make sense !

    ' etc. etc.

End With ' closing the With
```

Comment: 20 congrats for the 20K :)

Comment: @A.S.H LOL, thanks :) now I have one more thing, chase the Gold Badge for VBA and Excel VBA

Comment: Yeah, so many questions out there to be closed on the spot :P