# Inserting data in multidimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I have to move data in my input files to another workbook. The data is structured in worksheets as hardcoded input as below where the column with all the identifiers is a named range called "INPUT_MARKER".

```
    IQ_SALES    100     200     300
    IS_MARGIN    20      30      40
    IQ_EBITDA    50      30      20
```

I only have to move some of the data. So for instance in the above I would only have to move the IQ_SALES data and IQ_EBITDA data. So I need to understand how to create an array of arrays with only the data that is needed.

The code below compares the data in the INPUT_MARKER column with elements in the array called "identifierArray" and I then intend to insert all of the row data in the multidimensional array called "bigDataArray". I have tried several approaches but have not been able to make this work. Would much appreciate any help. I have left out some of the redundant code in the below such that only the code pertaining to this problem is included.

```
    Sub Update()

    Dim identifierArray(), bigDataArray() As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Definition of the array of data that is to be transferred to the targetModel
    identifierArray = Array("IQ_SALES", "IQ_EBITDA")
    ReDim bigDataArray(1 To UBound(identifiersArray))

    With Workbooks(sourceModel).Sheets("DATA")
        For Each c In .Range("INPUT_MARKER")
            For Each element In identifierArray
                If element = c.Value Then
                    'To construct bigDataArray by inserting row data every time element equals c.Value

                End If
            Next element
        Next c
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does your `INPUT_MARKER` range begins with Column `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tackled a similar issue recently. This can be handled with a multi-dimensional array from the look of things

> *Though as a predisposition I'd recommend checking reference on [dynamic
>   multi-dimensional
>   arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363541/how-to-create-multi-dimensional-array-of-unknown-size)*

```
Private Sub fill_array()

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("DATA")

    For Each cell In ws.Range("INPUT_MARKER")
        If ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1) = "IQ_SALES" Or ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1) = "IQ_EBITDA" Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(0 To 2, i)
            arr(0, i) = ws.Cells(cell.Row, 2)
            arr(1, i) = ws.Cells(cell.Row, 3)
            arr(2, i) = ws.Cells(cell.Row, 4)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

So your array will have the structure of`arr(x, y)`, where:

- `x`  - `[0;2]` - will be the 3 columns of data you want to store
- `y`  - `n` - index of the array *(with only `IQ_SALES` and `IQ_EBITDA` being added)*

---

**EDIT:**

> *This is of course presuming, your data "`INPUT_MARKER`" starts at
>   Column `A`*

Also as an extra tip, if you want to also store information of the arrays source - in resemblence of a primary key, you can increment the first dimension

```
ReDim Preserve arr(0 to 3, i)
arr(3, i) = cell.Row              ' edited (instead of arr(3)= …)
```

and use example the `cell.Row` as a reference as to where the data was obtained from, in order to reverse trace the data

Comment: corrected assignment in EDIT from `arr(3) = …` to `arr(3, i) = cell.Row` :-)

Comment: @T.M. Good catch! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the range of the values you want to pick you can shortcut using:

```
Dim bigDataArray() As Variant
bigDataArray = Range(A1:D4)
```

This will set up the array with the same size as the range you pick up,
Then you can output the specific values you want from the array.

Comment: This would include the rows he does not want include and also it would be difficult to traverse.