# CreateTextFile error

Tags: vbscript

I am getting a 'Permission denied' error when trying to run this VBScript after dragging another file or folder icon onto the script's icon.

I have tried running it on two Windows 10 machines and if I run it with arguments if objects at the file creation line, otherwise the scripts completes normally.

Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO
Dim objShell

Dim fldTest
Dim fileTest
Dim strPath
Dim txsOutput

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set txsOutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Test.txt")

For Each strPath In WScript.Arguments
    fldTest = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    For Each fleTest In fldTest.Files
        ...
    Next
Next

txsOutput.Close()

Set txsOutput = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to achieve? Why are you dragging the file or folder over the vbs script?

Comment: Which line is the error in? `.GetFolder` returns an object, use `Set fldTest = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)`, also specify full path within `.CreateTextFile`, try to accumulate a data in a variable and then write it content into file at once (take a look at `Sub WriteTextFile()` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265363/2165759) answer).

Comment: If you're actually getting a permission denied error in the line `Set txsOutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Test.txt")` you're probably dropping another item on the script while it's still processing the first item or group of items. That invokes a *new* instance of the script, which tries to create the same file that the already running instance still has opened, thus causing the error.

Comment: the code which you have given is working fine for me and creating new file.But what is your requirement ?

Comment: I eventually traced the fault to strPath being incorrectly constructed in unshown code, found quickly after posting my plea for help.