# Function which Removes Only Non-ASCII characters in a column in access table

Tags: vba

I have a access table and i am writing a `vba` code to remove `non-ascii` characters from the table, i have tried using below two functions

```
Public Function removeall(stringData As String) As String
    Dim letter As Integer
    Dim final As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(stringData) 'loop thru each char in stringData

        letter = Asc(Mid(stringData, i, 1)) 'find the char and assign asc value

        Select Case letter 'Determine what type of char it is
            Case Is < 91 And letter > 64 'is an upper case char
                final = final & Chr(letter)
            Case Is < 123 And letter > 96 'is an lower case char
                final = final & Chr(letter)
            Case Is = 32  'is a space
                final = final & Chr(letter)
    End Select

    Next i
    removeall = final

    End Function
```

And also tried using below function

```
Public Function Clean(InString As String) As String
'-- Returns only printable characters from InString
   Dim x As Integer
   For x = 1 To Len(InString)
      If Asc(Mid(InString, x, 1)) > 31 And Asc(Mid(InString, x, 1)) < 127 Then
         Clean = Clean & Mid(InString, x, 1)
      End If
   Next x

End Function
```

But the problem is : In `removeall function` it removes everything including `#` and `space` characters.. And In `Clean function` also removes `special characters` as well.

I need a correct function which retains key board characters and removes all other characters

Examples of strings in tables are :

1) "ATTACHMENT FEEDING TUBE FITS 5-18 ºFR#   "

2) "CATHETER FOLEY 3WAY SILI ELAST 20FR 30ML LATEXº"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Output should be like

1) "ATTACHMENT FEEDING TUBE FITS 5-18 FR"

2) "CATHETER FOLEY 3WAY SILI ELAST 20FR 30ML LATEX"

Comment: "function which retains key board characters" - `#` is both an ASCII character and a 'keyboard character' (whatever that means - I can certainly see it on my keyboard), so why do you want it removed? What do you actually want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use a whitelist of accepted characters. e.g.

```
' You can set up your domain specific list:
Const Whitelist = "1234567890" & _
                  "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" & _
                  "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM" & _
                  " `~!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]{};:""'|\<>?/ –"

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print Clean("ATTACHMENT FEEDING TUBE FITS 5-18 ºFR#")
    Debug.Print Clean("CATHETER FOLEY 3WAY SILI ELAST 20FR 30ML LATEXº")

End Sub

Public Function isAllowed(char As String) As Boolean

    isAllowed = InStr(1, Whitelist, char, vbBinaryCompare) > 0

End Function


Public Function Clean(dirty As String) As String
'-- Returns only printable characters from dirty
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim c As String
   For x = 1 To Len(dirty)
      c = Mid(dirty, x, 1)
      If isAllowed(c) Then
         Clean = Clean & c
      End If
   Next x

End Function
```

Comment: ya, i added outputs, I will check with your code , thanks

Comment: it should retain the space as well, your code doesn't do that, Can you try to alter it and send me the correct code

Comment: You'll need to set up your whitelist to be exactly what you need. Don't forget about escaping the quotechar.

You can change the list yourself. Just add in the chars you need.

Comment: and also it should retain special characters

Comment: can you please give whitelists as well

Comment: i am confused with quotechars

Comment: Yes, this is an *example* You know exactly what chars you need, just change the whitelist at the top of the code yourself

Comment: If you want to use a quote in a string definition it needs to be escaped.
See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba

Comment: `~!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]{};:"'|\<>?/

Comment: can you add those as well

Comment: and how to deal with white space and other special characters

Comment: hi, thanks for your time and i will test with my table, I will upvote it as answers as soon as i get the desired result :)

Comment: Note that you can also use my answer to remove all non-ascii characters without working without working with a whitelist. There are some more obscure ascii characters that are hard to include.

Comment: Yeah, it was quite hard to understand from the Op what was actually required. He kept talking about ascii *and* special characters. Hence the white list as an extendable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Alternate approach that preserves ALL ASCII characters, without working with a whitelist, in a single function:

```
Public Function RemoveNonASCII(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If AscW(Mid(str, i, 1)) < 127 Then 'It's an ASCII character
            RemoveNonASCII = RemoveNonASCII & Mid(str, i, 1) 'Append it
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: It was quite hard to understand from the Op what was actually required. He kept talking about ascii *and* special characters. Hence the white list as an extendable solution above

Comment: Yes, I understand your approach. But for future reference (anyone coming here actually seeking to remove non-ASCII characters from a string, by googling for example), mine is simpler and does not require a list of all ASCII characters. It does not remove the `#`, of course, since that's a valid ASCII character

Comment: I agree yours is simpler and is what I would have gone for if the OP had simply asked for the retention of ascii. However he also asked to retain keyboard characters. The pound sterling symbol (U+00A3) is on the keyboard but is not ascii.

Comment: I don't see how the pound sterling symbol is relevant, `#` is an octothorpe, ASCII character 35. My intention is not to only help OP, but mostly to provide a useful reference