# Add formula with variables to active cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to add a formula to the ActiveCell. The formula shall contain 2 variables one being a string the other one being a range.

i.e.

```
x = "This is my string variable"

y = cell.Address
```

I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & x & y
```

The cell should contain the string variable and the value of the variable containing the address. The behavior should be the same as if I would type `="Some string"&$a$1` into a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the variable x in quotes, and add the ampersand, like so:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & x & Chr(34) & "&" & y
```

Another way is to double up on quotes:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=""" & x & """&" & y
```

This is a good answer to that part:
[How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

UPDATED FOR BRACKETS AROUND Y, and some variables to make reading it easier:

```
    Sub Blah()
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strCellRef As String
    Dim strDoubleQuotes As String

    Dim strSpace As String

        strText = "This is my string variable"
        strCellRef = "$A$1"

        strDoubleQuotes = Chr(34)
        strSpace = " "

       ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & strDoubleQuotes & strText & strSpace & _
                        strDoubleQuotes & "&" & strDoubleQuotes & "(" & strDoubleQuotes & "&" & strCellRef & "&" & strDoubleQuotes & ")" & strDoubleQuotes

    End Sub
```

Comment: np, I always use chr(34) just because I find it easier to read

Comment: Jpad Limited, is there some sort of pattern or guideline how to add the double quotes ? I tried to add another string but didn't succeed

Comment: not sure what you mean, any string variable will need quotes around it.. example?

Comment: ActiveCell.Formula = "=""" & x & "" & "" & ( & "" "&" & y

Want to add () around y

Comment: It's an ugly business:

       ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & x & " " & Chr(34) & "&" & Chr(34) & "(" & Chr(34) & "&" & y & "&" & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(34)

I have added some more code to my original answer

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for your time and solution :) .. I think I'll write a small script to auto add double quotes, maybe others find it also confusing .

Comment: it's very easy to write a function to auto add them, but it is more code to call it each time than to just add them.....

The real issue here is knowing when you need to use them, and also the ampersand. Which I think generally comes from experience.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. Still I think it would be nice if you had a small app where you could choose what you want to do (add a formula, values, etc), add the values you want in the cell, press a button and get the correct format back. You think that wouldn't be easily achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""This is my string variable"" & RC[+1]"
```

where R[rowoffset]C[columnoffset] points to the cell relative to the active cell.
In my example RC[+1] is the cell right to the active cell (at the same row)