# Excel macro to replace tags with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to replace some text and tags in an exported qml file.

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<CONTENT>", "</CONTENT>")
```

But now i want to replace a tag with variable as below:

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<CONTENT ID="0">", "<CONTENT ID="0"><![CDATA[")
```

I appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: what's the value of sTemp ? are you reading a xml file ?

Comment: Are you just struggling with the inner doublequotes? Then double them like "<CONTENT ID=""0"">"

Comment: Hi Asger, I tried your solution but I am getting Compile Error Expected: List Separator or ). The code i tried is as below:
`sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<CHOICE ID=""0"">, "<CHOICE ID=""0""><![CDATA[")`.

Comment: Please see my answer: You just need one more " directly before the comma. If it works fine for you, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment below my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Replace` needs two string parts.
Their limiting doublequotes have to remain like they are shown here:

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "...", "...")
```

If you exchange each ... by your strings, double each of **their** doublequotes,
but leave the above limiting ones as they are.

Examples:

```
Doublequote somewhere in the middle: <CONTENT ID="0">
                                     <CONTENT ID="0"><![CDATA[
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<CONTENT ID=""0"">", "<CONTENT ID=""0""><![CDATA[")
```

---

```
Doublequote at the end: ID="0"
                        "ID=1"
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "ID=""0""", """ID=1""")
```

---

```
Double-Doublequote: =IF(A1="you got it","yeah :)","")
Range.Formula = "=IF(A1=""you got it"",""yeah :)"","""")"
```