# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting using Special Char

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I am trying to insert some conditional formatting in Excel so when you go into the Conditional Formatting settings the formula reads:
=$K11="✓" however I haven't had any luck at all.

The code I have is shown below but it doesn't seem to work, that just throws an error.

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$SK11=""" & ChrW(&H2713)
```

The below kind of works but it shows as `="$SK11=✓"` in the settings so its added an extra quotation mark at the front and is missing the quotation mark before the tick

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="$SK11=" & ChrW(&H2713)
```

Comment: Try building the string using Chr(34) instead of Doublequotes. Something like `Formula1:="=$K11=" & Chr(34) & ChrW(&H2713) & Chr(34)`

Comment: Further info/Other solutions: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Comment: In the text you mention `K11`; in the code it's `SK11"`. Which is correct?