# How do I concatenate multiple cells using structured references for excel tables in vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate multiple columns and separate each by a "-". When ever I run the below code, it gives me a type mismatch error. How can I make the types align or at least allow the cells concatenate ?

The concatenate works whenever I remove the hyphen(-) but once I put it or any other value not a column it fails. Please help, I can't seem to clear this error. Can I get help making it concatenate with the (-)? I have tried removing the range. I have tried range.Value instead of range.formula and it still does not work

```
Range("Table2[New_app]").Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(Input2!$Q2,AppRef,3,false),0)" 'This is a previous line of code that works 

'This is the code that is not working 
Range("Table2[[MIS-MONTH]]").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Table2[New_Name], " - ", Table2[Month])"
```

the result should be something like this:

```
Column1content-Column2content-Column3content
```

However I keep getting run time error '13'  Type Mismatch

Comment: [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba). As is, the code is subtracting one string from another, well trying to. You need to double up the quotes around the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Extra quotes seems to allow this to work based on a quick test I did.

```
Range("A12").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,"" - "",B2)"
```

Updated your code to match

```
Range("Table2[[MIS-MONTH]]").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Table2[New_Name], "" - "", Table2[Month])"
```

Comment: Yes. Because otherwise it's like trying to do  `Range("A12").Formula = "=x" - "x"`. Trying to subtract one string from another will throw a Type Mismatch.