# Excel formula escape characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a below formula which works in excel, in a cell.

```
="D"&AC2 & REPT(" ",12 - LEN(AC2))&REPT(" ", 20)&T2&REPT(" ", 3 - LEN(T2))&AD2&REPT(" ", 2 - LEN(AD2))&REPT(" ",12)
```

I tried to translate this to VBA, For letter `D` and all the whitespaces `" "` I used escape characters (i thought, they are escape characters) `"""" """"` but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's the formula I tried in VBA

```
"= """"D""""&AC2 & REPT("""" """" ,12 - LEN(AC2))&REPT("""" """", 20)&T2&REPT("""" """" , 3 - LEN(T2))&AD2&REPT("""" """" , 2 - LEN(AD2))&REPT("""" """" ,12)"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You got a bit quote happy there: `"=""D""&AC2 & REPT("" "",12 - LEN(AC2))&REPT("" "", 20)&T2&REPT("" "", 3 - LEN(T2))&AD2&REPT("" "", 2 - LEN(AD2))&REPT("" "",12)"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA you'll need quotation marks around a quotation mark from a formula `" -> """`

So, a whitespace would be `"" ""`, and a quoted string `""D""`

Comment: Why would you downvote and not clarify why you think the answer is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simpler method of implementing it in VBA is as below.

**Step 1:** Copy formula as it is in VBE Window

`="D"&AC2 & REPT(" ",12 - LEN(AC2))&REPT(" ", 20)&T2&REPT(" ", 3 - LEN(T2))&AD2&REPT(" ", 2 - LEN(AD2))&REPT(" ",12)`

**Step 2:** Highlight formula text and then for selected text, do FIND and REPLACE

FIND: "

REPLACE:""

`=""D""&AC2 & REPT("" "",12 - LEN(AC2))&REPT("" "", 20)&T2&REPT("" "", 3 - LEN(T2))&AD2&REPT("" "", 2 - LEN(AD2))&REPT("" "",12)`

**Step 3:** Wrap the outcome with a pair of quotes.

`"=""D""&AC2 & REPT("" "",12 - LEN(AC2))&REPT("" "", 20)&T2&REPT("" "", 3 - LEN(T2))&AD2&REPT("" "", 2 - LEN(AD2))&REPT("" "",12)"`

**Note:** If you are having ";" as argument separator then you need look at `FormulaLocal` and if you choose to use `Formula` then ";" shall be replaced by ",".