# How are the double-quotes managed when I put this code into a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

On SO, I was just given two answers that both work when called a single time. Now I want to put them in a loop and loop over several rows of data. However, I'm having a heck of time getting the code correct. I'm suspect it has to how I'm handling the double quotes.

The stand alone code lines are as follows.

1. `Var = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("And(A1:F1)")` and
2. `Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("A1:F1"))`

for the first example I tried:

```
for i = 2 to 20
     Var = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("And(A & i & :F & i)")
Next i
```

This produces "Error 2015"

for the second:

```
for i = 2 to 20
     Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("A" & i & ":F" & i))
Next i
```

This produces a line of red code

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variables should not be inside the quotes.

Comment: The second attempt looks perfect to me (I just copied and pasted and get no issues). The first attempt could be written as: `Var = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("And(A" & i & ":F" & i & ")")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Comment: @alowflyingpig not really - that one's about escaping `"` double quotes; here it's about concatenating VBA variables into a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Basic Editor is making this harder than it should be, because its default syntax highlighting is making string literals the same color as identifiers:

[image: default syntax highlighting makes both identifiers and string literals black]

You can change that under Tools/Options, and make *Identifier Text* a different color - here teal:

[image: VBE syntax highlighting options]

Now string literals are still black, but now identifiers *look* visually distinctive:

[image: string literal is now obviously not an identifier]

What you want to make sure, is that your variables are syntax-highlighted like identifiers - so they're teal, not black - like in your second example:

[image: variable i is clearly not a string literal]

Contrast with your first attempt, where `i` doesn't get syntax-highlighted as the identifier it should be:

[image: the entire string is all black]

And since you *know* that `i` is a VBA variable and you *want* VBA to concatenate its value into this string, then `i` being syntax-highlighted as any other string literal (and not as an identifier) is your visual cue that something's off!

Compare to [@JNevill's fixed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328692/how-are-the-double-quotes-managed-when-i-put-this-code-into-a-loop/59328958#comment104856879_59328692):

[image: i is now treated as an identifier]

With *Identifier Text* having a different syntax highlighting than string literals in the editor, it becomes much easier to quickly locate a variable that's accidentally inside a string literal.

That first snippet isn't working, because `ActiveSheet.Evaluate` takes its parameter and gives it to Excel's expression evaluation engine, ...which has no idea what to do with this `i`. Variable `i` only exists in the execution context of the VBA code: only VBA code can evaluate its value.

Comment: Side note: while you're in that dialog, consider swapping Courier New for Consolas =)