# VBA inserting a Formula in a Cell Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, formula

I want to insert the following formula into a cell and drag it it down. The dragging part is done.

I keep getting Error 1004. Suggestions on how to do this?

```
SourceSheet.Range("k1").Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Check!A:C,3,0)="",VLOOKUP('Template'!A2,Check!A:C,2,0),VLOOKUP(A2,Check!A:C,3,0)),"")="","",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Check!A:C,3,0)="",VLOOKUP('Template'!A2,Check!A:C,2,0),VLOOKUP(A2,Check!A:C,3,0)),""))"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba

Comment: All `"` inside the string must be doubled `""`

Comment: Don't drag a formula down either - you can write it to an entire range in one line.

Comment: @BigBen, how can I do that?!?!

Comment: `SourceSheet.Range("k1:k100").Formula = ...`

Comment: Amazing!! Never thoughts of that one, thank you everyone  game changer for me!

Comment: One question. How does excel update the formula reference (example A2 to A3 and so on) if the VBA code has a range with the same formula?? It worked perfectly, but I'm not sure I get the logic behind it.