# EXCEL VBA, IF odd and even row

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I get this code in this forum, but I don't know how to give condition example if "A16" is not empty than "B16" can show either "YES" or "NO". If "A16" is empty, than nothing to show?

```
Sub OddRowAlert()
With Range("B16:B100")  
.Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(B16),2)),"YES","NO")"  
.Formula = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So you asked a question that was closed as duplicate, and immediately opened a new one with exactly the same text? Wow. Btw: SO is *not* a forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Formula = "=IF(A16="""","""",IF((MOD(ROW(B16),2)),""YES"",""NO""))"
```

Comment: It's not produce "YES" or "NO", it's just show "FALSE" even if "A16" is empty or not.

Comment: Sorry, quotation marks need to be doubled in the VBA in order to produce single quotation marks in the output. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: If you don't mind, one more question... Let say, now, ignore the odd and even. I want duplicate same statement every 3 row. Example, I want repeat "2017" for first row, "2018" second row, "2019" third row, and repeat "2017" for fourth row, "2018" for  fifth row and so on...

Comment: Please limit your questions to one per topic.