# Putting Formula that covers space in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would really appreciate a help here.
I have a formula in cell C4 like this one

```
=INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!D4")
```

To get the value of cell D4 in other sheet which name is written in B4

***Excel Cells Appearance***

[image]

***Sheet appearance***

[image]

I realized that sheet has 'space' in it hence the excel formula above.
But when i try to put this formula in VBA, it gives me an error. and the formula is highlighted in green.

In VBA

[image]

> Sheets("Data").Range("C4").Select
> ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDIRECT(" '"&B4&"'!D4")"

I don't understand it since i'm really an amateur in VBA.
What should i do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

Try below. You have to adjust spaces exactly as sheet name.

```
Sub SpaceIndir()
    Sheets("Data").Range("C4").Formula = "=INDIRECT(' " & B4 & "'!D4)"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, Thanks for editing and trying to help, i eventually found the way to do it by manually recording a macro and look how the formula is formed in VBA. i Didn't think about this before, but the formula looks like this

>"=INDIRECT(""'""&B4&""'!D4"")"

Thank you