# Inserting formula as string into a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, quotes

It seems to be a problem with some characters in it

My original formula in the worksheet (working):

> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zazmluvnenia").Cells("3", "AM").Value = "=Výkony!M4 & ", " & TEXT(Výkony!J4;"d.m.yyyy") & ", " & TEXT(Výkony!K4;"hh:mm")"

Putting this into VBA doesn't work because of the quotes. I tried to solve the problem this way: [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba/9024764#9024764)

I changed my code according to the answers on the question above:

```vb
"=Výkony!M3 & " & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & " & TEXT(Výkony!J3;" & Chr(34) & "d.m.yyyy" & Chr(34) & ") & " & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & " & TEXT(Výkony!K3;" & Chr(34) & "hh:mm" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

And error '1004' occurred.

Answer (score 0):

### Double Quotes vs CHR(34)

- Your `CHR` solution was almost fine, but you didn't know that **VBA** doesn't recognize the semi-colon (`;`) as a separator like **Excel** does. You always have to replace every semi-colon (used as a separator) with a comma in **VBA**.
- Similarly **VBA** uses the dot (`.`) as the decimal separator.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SEMI()

    Dim strF As String
    
    ' Double double-quotes ("") in several rows.
    strF = "=Výkony!M4&"", """ _
         & "&TEXT(Výkony!J4,""d.m.yyyy"")&"", """ _
         & "&TEXT(Výkony!K4,""hh:mm"")"
    
    ' CHR(34) in several rows.
    strF = "=Výkony!M4&" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) _
         & "&TEXT(Výkony!J4," & Chr(34) & "d.m.yyyy" & Chr(34) & ")&" _
         & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) _
         & "&TEXT(Výkony!K4," & Chr(34) & "hh:mm" & Chr(34) & ")"
    
    ' Double double-quotes ("") in one row.
    strF = "=Výkony!M4&"", ""&TEXT(Výkony!J4,""d.m.yyyy"")&"", ""&TEXT(Výkony!K4,""hh:mm"")"
    
    ' CHR(34) in one row.
    strF = "=Výkony!M4&" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "&TEXT(Výkony!J4," & Chr(34) & "d.m.yyyy" & Chr(34) & ")&" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "&TEXT(Výkony!K4," & Chr(34) & "hh:mm" & Chr(34) & ")"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zazmluvnenia").Cells("3", "AM").Value = strF

End Sub
```