# VBA Shell strips quotes from PowerShell command line

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm trying to convert windows CRLF newline to UNIX LF newline with a POWERSHELL command. I would like a VBA macro to do that.

So far my code is:

```vb
Sub conversiontoUNIX()    
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim file As String, listfichiers As Variant, outputfolder As String, replace As String, command_shell As Variant
    outputfolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\" & "run_param_" & Format(Date, "dd_mm_yy")
    listfichiers = listfiles(outputfolder)
    
    For filx = LBound(listfichiers) To UBound(listfichiers)
    file = outputfolder & "\" & listfichiers(filx)
    Requst = "PowerShell -noexit -Command (Get-Content " & file & ") -join ""`n"" > " & file & ""

    command_shell = Shell(Requst, vbNormalFocus)
    Next filx
End Sub
```

I run into an error:
[image: PowerShell error]

How can i manage to run my code ?

Best regards,

Jouvzer

Comment: check your command first. Do a `Debug.Print Requst` get the result from the immediate window. Open up a command shell in Windows, copy the command from the immediate window there and run it. Does it work or error?

Comment: When i copy the command in a shell window it is working

Comment: Je suis desolée. Je ne parle pas Français.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need backslashes to preserve quotes around **`n** in command line:

```
Requst = "PowerShell -noexit -Command (Get-Content " & file & _
      ") -join \""`n\"" > " & file & ""
```

Comment: Seems you have to escape double-quotes with [extra double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba) in VBA, not with backslashes.  Am I missing something about how the quotes are interpreted by Shell()?

Comment: @Rich Moss [A double quote mark preceded by a backslash (\") is interpreted as a literal double quote mark (")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160).
[Everyone quotes command line arguments the wrong way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way)

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the `""` was removed and the backtick-newline character is not understood. Try adding another pair of double quotes around the
`n